# Why is Python Printing out multiple values here?

Tags: python

I am writing this function to test the primality of numbers, I know that it is not the best code but I would wish it prints out **Not prime** when a number is not prime and **Is prime** when a number is prime. The problem is that it prints out **Not prime** then **Is prime** for numbers that are not prime...
For example this code:

```
def isPrime(n):
  for i in range(2, n):
    if n%i==0:
        print "Not Prime!"
        break
  print "Is Prime"

isPrime(5)
isPrime(18)
isPrime(11)
```

Prints out.

```
Is Prime
Not Prime!
Is Prime
Is Prime
```

Help me out, What should I do? I am a beginner.

Comment: `break` is not `return`. After `break` execution continues after loop body. And after loop body you have  a line `print "Is Prime"`

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Thank you very much I now understand how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fix (python 3)

```
def isPrime(n):
  prime = True
  for i in range(2, n):
    if n%i==0:
        print("Not Prime!")
        prime = False
        break
  if prime:
      print("Is Prime") 

isPrime(5)
isPrime(18)
isPrime(11)
```

The problem in the code you posted is that the last `print` is always executed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I now understand the problem, it was really bugging my Head.

Answer (score 1):

`break` doesn't exist out of a function -- it just exits a loop. So as soon as you print "Not prime", you exit the loop and move on to the next print statement.

replace the `break` with the keyword `return` instead. `return` will immediately exit the function, returning the value you give the return statement, or `None` if you just put `return` with no value next to it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I thought that break escapes the function.